# Do i need a JSframework?

Tags: angularjs, ember.js

I want to add some JS functionality to our site. (wishlist, inquiry, ect) I think it would be nice for the UX that it is going to be build with some JS code

Do i need a JSframework like Angular, ember ect ? Or are JSframeworks only make sense for SPA like editing/backend tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That decision is up to you. AngularJS is awesome, but it's not really meant to be used for little pieces of a project. For my taste, I'd write everything with AngularJS. You probably want to check out Backbone if you want to only use it here and there.

From Backbonejs.org:

> Philosophically, Backbone is an attempt to discover the minimal set of
>   data-structuring (models and collections) and user interface (views
>   and URLs) primitives that are generally useful when building web
>   applications with JavaScript. In an ecosystem where overarching,
>   decides-everything-for-you frameworks are commonplace, and many
>   libraries require your site to be reorganized to suit their look,
>   feel, and default behavior — Backbone should continue to be a tool
>   that gives you the freedom to design the full experience of your web
>   application.

Angular is more like the "overarching, decides-everything-for-you frameworks" it mentions.

Comment: thanks...i going to look at backbone

Comment: I have to agree with m59 here, Angular is too big if you want just a part of your page. I would advise you to check out knockoutjs also. It migh be more suitable if your use case involves more DOM manipulation.